# How to maintain position after search filter in a recyclerview in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

can anyone tell how to maintain the position of items in recyclerview when a search filter has been implemented?

well the scenario is that when I search for item D which is in the 4 position the intent activity that is for item D became item A intent which is not what i want.

What i want is if I search for item D the activity for item D remains the same.

this problem is giving me stress for 2 days now so if anyone can help i will really appreciate it.

**Here is my code for my RecyclerView Adapter**

```
  public class dog_recylerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<dog_recylerAdapter.dogViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<dog_counter> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    Context dog_context;
    public static int tag;

    dog_recylerAdapter(ArrayList<dog_counter> arrayList, Context dog_context) {
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        this.dog_context = dog_context;
    }

    @Override
    public dogViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.petbook_dog, parent, false);
        return new dogViewHolder(view, dog_context, arrayList);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(dogViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.dog.setImageResource(arrayList.get(position).getCount());
        holder.dog_name.setText(arrayList.get(position).getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return arrayList.get(position).getCount();
    }

    public static class dogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        ImageButton dog;
        TextView dog_name;
        ArrayList<dog_counter> arrayList;
        Context dog_context;

        public dogViewHolder(View itemView, Context dog_context, ArrayList<dog_counter> arrayList) {
            super(itemView);
            this.arrayList = arrayList;
            this.dog_context = dog_context;
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            dog = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.petdog_imag1);
            dog_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.petdog_name1);
            dog.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
            if(position==0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this.dog_context, dog_alaskan_malamute.class);
                this.dog_context.startActivity(intent);
            }
            else if(position==1) {
                dog.setOnClickListener(this);
                Intent intent = new Intent(this.dog_context, dog_beagle.class);
                this.dog_context.startActivity(intent);
            }
            else if(position==2) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this.dog_context, dog_chow_chow.class);
                this.dog_context.startActivity(intent);
            }
            else if(position==3) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this.dog_context, dog_duchshand.class);
                this.dog_context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }

    public void setFilter(ArrayList<dog_counter> newList) {
        arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
        arrayList.addAll(newList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add tag to your views which implement `onClickListener` and later get the tag and do whatever you want based on them.

for example :

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(dogViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.dog.setImageResource(arrayList.get(position).getCount());
    holder.dog_name.setText(arrayList.get(position).getName());
    holder.dog.setTag(arrayList.get(position));
}
```

and in your on click listener :

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //int position = getAdapterPosition();
        dog_counter clickedItem=(dog_counter) v.getTag();
        arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
        // here do whatever you want with cliekdItem and not with the position
        //////............
     }
```

Comment: sir this might be silly question but what will i compare to clickedItem?

Comment: i do not know what is your dog counter model. lets think there is an id in there. or the dog counter name. whatever make it unique. you can use that as indicator that you clicked on what @tyreklGana-an

Comment: thank's sir it works now but now their this error that occur sometimes.          java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder{a7a1dbe position=1 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 no parent}

Comment: which line does the error happen on ? please edit your code and post your full code again @tyreklGana-an